# What is the meaning of כמר used as an honorific before introducing one's name?

Tags: minhag, names, translation

It is standard among Jews writing in Hebrew to attach the honorific כמר before introducing one's name. This custom is actually quite old dating back at least to the days of the earliest Acharonim, and possibly even earlier than that. But does anyone know what it means? This word has always baffled me. מר in Aramaic means "Lord" (or the English [Mister](https://www.google.com/search?q=mister%20etymology&safe=strict&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS906US907&sxsrf=ALeKk03KMjJ9JlqNiKvCEev3HDa3OIybOw%3A1623873883180&ei=W1nKYN_JComVwbkPnIWSmA0&oq=mister%20ety&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMggIABAWEAoQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBQgAEIYDOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgcIABCxAxBDOgQIABBDOgUIABCxAzoICC4QxwEQowI6BQguELEDOggILhDHARCvAToICC4QsQMQkwI6AgguUNYtWLJLYO1UaAFwAngAgAG3BogB2ROSAQkwLjguMi42LTGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)), but why is there the letter כ in the beginning? A literal translation in Aramaic would yield "like the lord", which really makes no sense as an honorific or title. Any insight?

Comment: For something that is "standard among Jews writing in Hebrew", I have never seen this honorific. Could you please give some examples of its usage?

Comment: Might it be an abbreviation? כבוד מעלת רב

Comment: It's not likely to be an abbreviation. I've never seen it with quotation marks. It seems to be a complete word/idea.

Comment: Like robev, I have never seen it either; so I seriously question calling it a "standard". A "komer" (whether spelled malei כומר or chaseir כמר) is a pagan priest, so I don't find this likely.

Comment: Some suggestions [here](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=54858)

Comment: @ba thanks for the link.

Comment: Micha, the fact that you haven't seen it regrettably does not make it any less standard.

Comment: @Bach, I have seen this in the teshuvos of the achronim, but not so frequently that I could find an example at my fingertips. Could you provide an example or two?

Comment: Our honorable teacher…

Comment: No one has yet provided a single example of its usage...

Comment: @robev people don't feel they need to provide examples for something they see every day, as mentioned, in almost all wedding invitations in their circles. But here are two older examples in sefurim https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=36587#p=17&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%A8 and https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=1937#p=13&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%A8

Answer (score 1):

https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10386-mar

I always understood that the word "Mar" was used in the Talmud to refer to someone on the caliber of Rav (see article above) and later generations used the word "Kemar" meaning "like a Mar" but not exactly a Mar since that's reserved for earlier generations.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You often find this used on a chasuna invitation, but im not to sure its an honorific in context it is used "the praiseworthy pious chosid K'mar" seems to me it is saying "like the master"  as in the previous honorifics in the sentence are appropriate for this individual